# Can i upload/embed a Video inside a discussion board item without writting code

Tags: 2013, development, html, video

I have a list of type Discussion board, and i want to upload Videos to a discussion board. So when someone upload a video, the video should be embedded inside the item body field, and users can start the video immediately. is this supported inside sharepoint?

now i try to upload a file of type .mp4 inside the discussion board body fied, where the video was added as a link, as follow:-

[image]

while i was searching for an appraoch whihc allow end users to embed the Video inside the item body, so users can start watching the video right-away without having to open it inside their client application (as in Youtube case).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The OOTB Discussion board uses a rich textfield, thus you can upload and embed images, videos etc.

If you embed a video from an external site, for example Youtube you get a lots of options to add parameters like autostart and such to the URL. (autoplay=1)

**Edit**

It's important that the video is stored as a Video content type. Use the default image library in your site to store the videos or create a new library of the type "Assets Library".

Comment: The videos we are planning to upload will be uploaded to sharepoint they do not exsits inside external sites... now when i try to upload a .mp4 file,, i will only get a link to the video , so users can not watch the video right away as in let say Youtube case..hope this explain my question

Comment: now i chose to store the Video inside the site assets folder (the defualt folder).. so where i need to upload it instead?

Comment: Any library that does have the video content type assigned. Or you can just create a new image library from the ootb list templates.

Comment: now i added a new "Picture library" but it doe not have Videos CT ? so is there another list which provide the Video content type by defualt ?

Comment: Assets Library.. is this a publishing site?

Comment: no this is a Team site that does not have any publishing features enabled

Comment: Now i added a custom list , then i added the built-in Video content type to it. now i uploaded a new video to the discussion board , and i chose the video CT, but seems the video will be added as a link inside discussion item body, and when i click on the link it will open on another window and start playing the video but my question was how i can get this video embeded inside the discussion item directly ?

Comment: Add the video to your library as a video content type > go back and create a new discussion. Select the Body field and then select insert from the toolbar > video from SharePoint and then select the video from the library where you uploaded it and insert it.

Comment: seems for non-publishing sites i do not have the option to directly insert Videos,, i only have the option to insert>>upload file... seems weird..

Comment: Sadly i don't have time to test this in a non publishing site for now, but it might be that the publishing feature is required to embed a video in SharePoint.